# How can I change the resolution of the login screen?

Tags: login, resolution, lightdm

I have Linux Mint 20 running on my laptop. I have a dual monitor setup connected by VGA. The laptop monitor is 1366x768 and the external one is 1360x768. I went through a lot of hoops to get the correct resolution on the desktop, had to set up Modelines manually (something that is "arcaic" apparently) and that did the trick, but the login screen is still messed up.

See, my second monitor defaulted to 1024x768 before I manually set the new modeline with xrandr, but this change doesn't apply to the login screen. Both screens mirror, and because the second one is in 1024x768 resolution, my laptop sets to that resolution as well, but it's not even stretched. The login screen appears in a square window on the left side of the screen, leaving a big black bar to the right. This is annoying, but the most annoying part is that I tried 20 different solutions and none made a single thing.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution) is the questions I've been reffering to for most of my testing. I swear to god I tried almost all of the solutions provided there to no avail. I tried to copy the "monitors.xml" file found in ~/.config (it's called "cinnamon-monitors.xml" on this distro) to /var/lib/lightdm/.config both with both names, none worked. I tried to make the "lightdmxrandr.sh" script that set the mode on my primary monitor to the desired one, then made it executable and put it in /usr/share, then added the script to "lightdm.conf". This did something for once, it made the lightdm service crash on startup (I doubled checked, the resolution was correct, and I tried to run it on the desktop and it did work as intended). I had to edit the file to get to my desktop again. I also tried to edit the grub config, with the neeed "update-grub" after that, didn't work. I tried a variation of the script that created a new mode and added it to my monitor and then set it to it, didn't work.

You can see where I'm going with this, no matter what I do the login screen stays the same, and it's a shame because I want to make it look nice. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your frustration. Regarding the solution you have linked, and assuming that the script `lightdmxrandr.sh` is correct, I see a couple of points where it could go wrong.

**1.** It is possible that LightDM simply does not have the *permission* to execute `lightdmxrandr.sh` even though you have made it executable.
After moving `lightdmxrandr.sh` to `/usr/share`, you may transfer the
ownership of the file to LightDM by

```
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm /usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

This might instantly fix the problem after reboot.

**2.** Make sure that the `display-setup-script=/usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh` hook is under the `[Seat:*]` section in the configuration file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. E.g., the configuration file should look like

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=/usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

(possibly with other hooks, of course, see https://github.com/canonical/lightdm#configuration)

**3.** Instead of `display-setup-script`, you might also try `greeter-setup-script`, i.e.,

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

You might also want to check out this [related discussion](https://gist.github.com/RyanMillerC/c48d9f63f8fe386b22a7da18cf6913d2) on Github. I hope that you'll find a way to solve this!

Comment: I'm no longer using this system (currently on Manjaro, no dual monitor setup) but these are good steps regardless. Don't know if I should accept it as an answer tho because I don't know if it would actually work but thanks, it may be helpful to somebody in the future.

Comment: No worries! Just for the record: I was also in a similar situation, trying out a dozen suggestions from various forums without success (either the login screen would not change at all, or LightDM would crash at startup, requiring me to fix things via a virtual console). In my case, transferring the ownership of the script file to LightDM (as explained in 1.) was the key, which eventually made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a lot of distribution, I just had to say I tried the display options, I tried the grub, and I tried the graphic card option and nothing helped. The only thing that helped me is changing the resolution of the lightdm log in manager.

Here is the website with the full explanation of how to do it:
https://sudo-juice.com/lightdm-resolution/

*And one thing*
"xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080" = two lines not one

"display-setup-script=/usr/share/lightdmxrandr.sh" = and this is with one
cause the original one is not working for me.

Hope it helps